# Link inside input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I need to add a link inside an input (right), and that the input also goes out its value (left).

It would be the value of the input on the left side and a link (which opens a modal) to the right. Both inside the input box.

Can anyone help me how can I get it?

```
<input ng-model="detalleTicketController.identificacion.scheduledJobCode" type="text" class="form-control"
      id="codTrabajoProg" name="codTrabajoProg" disabled>
      <a ng-click="detalleTicketController.modalScheduledWorksDetail();" >link</a>
    </input>
```

Comment: You cannot have elements inside an input element in html. You can position it over it with css though

Comment: Short answer. You shouldn't do something like that. At least in HTML5 that's not valid markup. You can check it here https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot place any element inside an input element.You have to position(relative to its positioned parent) the link using css.

Like this:

```css
.inputContainer {
  position: relative;
}
.linkInsideInput {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="inputContainer">
  <input ng-model="detalleTicketController.identificacion.scheduledJobCode" type="text" class="form-control"
      id="codTrabajoProg" name="codTrabajoProg" disabled/>
 <a class="linkInsideInput" ng-click="detalleTicketController.modalScheduledWorksDetail();">link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: I would add a cursor to the CSS as well. https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/hqozejnn/